# I'm having trouble with changing parts of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on a small game to play in the console. I'm trying to make player movement, but when I try to replace a certain element within the `level` array, it deletes the rest of the array.

The only movement in the code right now is moving right (type `2` in the console to move right)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define con std::cout <<
#define newline std::cout << '\n'
#define text std::cin >>
#define end return 0
#define repeat while (true)

int width, height;
int rprog;
int x, y, z;
int playerpos;
int input;
double level[] = 
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

const char *display[] = {"   ", "[ ]", "[X]"};

int render () {
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    while (x < 37) {
        z = level[x - 1];
        con display[z];
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 1;
        if (y == 7) {
            y = 1;
            newline;
        }
    }
    end;
}

int player () {
    con "Please make your next move : w: 1, a: 2, s: 3, d: 4";
    newline;
    con "Current position: " << playerpos;
    newline;
    text input;
    if (input == 2) {
        level[playerpos] = 0;
        playerpos = playerpos - 1;
        level[playerpos] = 3;
    }
    end;
}

int main() {
    playerpos = 15;
    while (true) {
        render ();
        player ();
    }
    end;
}
```

I'm using this website for coding currently: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

This is the output:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ]            [ ]
[ ]   [X]      [ ]
[ ]            [ ]
[ ]            [ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
Please make your next move : w: 1, a: 2, s: 3, d: 4
Current position: 15
2
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ]            [ ]
[ ]
```

And then it cuts off rendering the level.

I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, just don't do this ```#define``` things, it's awful, impossible to read code at all.

Comment: Best to get used to the syntax of C++ sooner rather than obfuscating your code with a bunch of `#define`s, I say :\

Comment: Why are you using an array of `double`, and not an array of `int`, or even an array of `enum`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Arrays

Array indices start with 0 in C++.

You set the item at the new position to 3:

```
level[playerpos] = 3;
```

However, your array for the display types has only 3 elements (0, 1, 2):

```
const char *display[] = {"   ", "[ ]", "[X]"};
```

Thus, you encounter undefined behaviour, as you have an out of bounds access.

Note also, that your initial array correctly uses a `2` for the player position, and thus works.

However, it also has a off-by-1 error: Your initialize the `playerpos = 15`, but place the `2` at index 14. Thus, the initial rendering is wrong. So the first movement will not be correct, and seem to stay on the same position.

#### Types

As @RemyLebeau mentions, why do you use a `double` array for the game state? Not only would other types be more appropriate, especially `double` can lead to serious, hard to debug probles. Not all integers are perfectly representable by a double, and type conversions could lead to different results.

Just for an example: if you add states 4 and 5, and imagine a double could not represent 5 exactely, but store it as 4.99999999999999999 instead. When accessing the array, integer conversion could render a state 4 instead.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and answer for details

#### Defines

As @KarenMelikyan mentioned in a comment, those `#define`s are a bad idea. It makes your code much harder to read for others, and is a bad a habit to develop. Better get aquainted with correct C++ syntax and use it.

Comment: Thanks, i made it a 2 and it rendered properly.